# Perron Frobenius Theorem modified

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, stochastic-matrices, nonnegative-matrices, page-rank

On this [site](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~mec/Winter2009/RalucaRemus/Lecture3/lecture3.html) I found a modified version of Perron Frobenius Theorem

> Perron-Frobenius Theorem: If M is a positive, column stochastic matrix, then:
>   1 is an eigenvalue of multiplicity one.
>   1 is the largest eigenvalue: all the other eigenvalues have absolute value smaller than 1.
>   the eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalue 1 have either only positive entries or only negative entries. In particular, for the eigenvalue 1 there exists a unique eigenvector with the sum of its entries equal to 1.

In this same site, in Disconnected components section there is a matrix

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1/2 & 1/2 \\
    0 & 0 & 1/2 & 0 & 1/2 \\
    0 & 0 & 1/2 & 1/2 & 0 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

This matrix satisfies the conditions therefore for the eigenvalue 1 there exists a unique eigenvector with the sum of its entries equal to 1.

but at least exists two vectors

$u = (1/2,1/2,0,0,0)$

$v = (0,0,1/3,1/3,1/3)$

what happened?
Is modified theorem incorrect?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $5\times5$ matrix is not positive. It has zero entries.

*Remark.* And that was probably the reason why Brin *et al.* introduced the so-called *damping factor* in their PageRank paper. Without the damping factor, their matrix is merely nonnegative and it might not possess a unique nonnegative eigenvector, i.e. the ranking is not unique. However, by introducing the damping factor (i.e. by considering a convex combination of their matrix with an all-one matrix), the matrix becomes positive and there is now a unique positive eigenvector (and thus a unique ranking).

Comment: You could, however, apply the theorem to non-negative matrices that satisfy additional criteria.  For instance, a unique eigenvector will exist if the matrix is irreducible and aperiodic (i.e. if the associated Markov chain is [ergodic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergodicity#Markov_chains) )